# If a function is continuous on $\mathbb R,$ does it follow that it is uniformly continuous on $(-1,1)?$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

I've been trying to think of counterexamples but the ideas I've had so far like $1/(x+1)$ and  $\sin(1/(x+1))$ don't work because those aren't continuous on all of $\mathbb R.$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it is continuous on the compact set $[-1,1]$, it is uniformly continuous on $[-1,1]$ and hence uniformly continuous on $(-1,1)$.

You can actually prove the converse. If $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(-1,1)$, then it can be extended to be uniformly continuous on $[-1,1].$

Comment: Okay; how would I show that a function uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$ is also uniformly continuous on $(a,b)?$

Comment: @justin: Doesn't it follow immediately from the definition?

Comment: Yes, it's just immediate application of the definition. More generally, if $f$ is uniformly continuous on $X$ and $Y\subset X$ then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $Y$.

Comment: That makes sense; thank you!